# Insert canvas picture to MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, canvas

Using Ajax to save a canvas generated picture to the server, which works perfectly well, but I also want to add the image name to a database table. This doesn't seem to work though.

Javascript:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST",'save.php',false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(imgurl);
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
// Get the data
$imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];


$filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

$random_digit=md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
$img = "img_" . $random_digit . ".png";


$fp = fopen( 'gallery/' . $img, 'wb' );
fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
fclose( $fp );

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table (imgurl) VALUES ('$img')");
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: given that the data you're stuffing into mysql is COMPLETELY unrelated to the actual canvas post (e.g. you're not inserting the post data - you're just generating a random string and inserting that string), what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The string im generating is the name of the image file. So I want to store the name of the image in the column "imgurl", but nothing happens :<

Comment: yes, but like I said. your filename has NOTHING to do with the canvas stuff. You could rip out ALL of the canvas code and you'd still be inserting a random filename string into the DB.

Comment: True, but still nothing is inserted the DB, and I can't figure out why :-p

Comment: so stop assuming that your query calls will never fail. `mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con))`.

Comment: Not getting any errors, se comment on answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO table (imgurl) VALUES ('$img')") or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Do you receive an error output?

Comment: 'table' is the table name, imgurl is the column.
Like

    `mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO images (imgurl) VALUES ('$img')");`

Should be correct?

Comment: Oh must be late. Could you try the updated answer and see if you get any error output.

Comment: Not getting any errors/output at all (nothing in FireFox Console either, don't know if it would output there anyway). Not sure if it's because the Ajax the site isn't refreshed or something?

Comment: Sorry I typed out `mysql_query` and `mysql_error` instead of `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_error`.  Updated answer again. Regardless - do you have php `error_reporting` turned on? It would not output to your FireFox Console - that is where clientside javascript errors would show up.

Comment: No errors, and nothing gets inserted to DB. 

`mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO meme (key) VALUES ('$img')") or die(mysqli_error());`

Comment: I believe that it might have something to do with `ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, was a stupid mistake. On the real database I did not use the column_name `imgurl`, but the reserved name `key`.